# Given $f:(0,\infty ) \to \mathbb{R}$ Can we say that $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$ exists?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Given $f:(0,\infty ) \to \mathbb{R}$, can we say that $\lim_{x\to \infty}$ f(x) exists?

And can we say that finite $\implies$ $f$ is bounded on $(0,\infty)$ ....I don't understand what "$\implies$" means. It was printed out in the same way.

Comment: '=>' means $\Rightarrow$ - implication

Comment: But $/implies$ symbol was correctly used in the previous questions of the same problem sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I wrongly assumed both that $f$ is continuous and that it is defined in $[0, \infty)$, instead of in $(0, \infty)$, as in the OP. Under my assumed conditions...

No, the limit does not always exist ( at least not as a standard Real number ), for example, take $f(x)=x$ . The function in this sense does not have a limit as $x \rightarrow \infty$, since f(x) grows without bounds. I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by 'finite => bounded'. As the other answer  and one of the comments pointed out, $f(x)$ being bounded does not imply that the limit exists; any periodic function is a counterexample . For completeness, as Hurkyl pointed out, when the function grows without bounds, the limit many not exist as a non-standard number.

If you mean to ask whether a finite limit implies $f(x)$ is bounded, the answer is yes (under the conditions in the EDIT): let $L$ be the limit. For fixed $\epsilon$ , there is an integer $N$ so that $|f(x)-L|< \epsilon $ for all $x>N$. And in the interval $[0,N]$ , f is a continuous function which takes on a (Real) maximum value $M$. Then $f(x)$ is bounded above by $$Max f(x): x\in [0,N], f(x)+\epsilon $$ and below by $$ Min f(x): x \in [0,N], f(x)- \epsilon $$.

Comment: I would guess that by saying does "finite $\implies$ $f$ is bounded"?, the OP means to ask if it is the case that having a finite limit when $x \rightarrow \infty$ implies that $f$ is bounded on $(0,\infty)$. But this is just a guess.

Comment: @AdriánBarquero: Seems reasonable.

Comment: Then $\cos x$ or $\cos x^2$ are counterexamples.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar: Do you mean a counterexample to $f$ bounded implies $Lim _{x \rightarrow \infty}$ exists?

Comment: The limit might not exist as an extended real number either; e.g. $x \sin x$.

Comment: @Hurkyl: you're right, but I assume we're restricting to Real-valued functions. And I did not say that if the function grows without bound the limit exists as an extended Real number.

Comment: It was never specified that $f$ is continuous, but even if we *were* to assume that $f:(0,\infty)\to\Bbb R$ is continuous, a finite limit in end-behavior needn't imply boundedness. Consider the function $f(x)=\frac1x$ for all $x>0$.

Comment: @CameronBuie: You're right, I somehow assumed we were working with $[0, \infty)$, that is why I used the compactness trick. My bad.

Comment: It's an easy mistake to make. I've made more such mistakes than I'd care to admit. :-/